# Anaconda Navigator asks to install applications every time

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently uninstalled Anaconda Navigator from C Drive and re-installed in D Drive , However each time I open Navigator and try to launch “Jupyterlab” or Notebook etc it only gives the option to "install "

After clicking install it first goes to C/ProgramData/Anaconda3 and says conda environment not found and only after clicking okay does it start looking in D/Anaconda where the actual packages/files are present .And this happens every time you close and relaunch the application

So how do I resolve this ? … i have searched and there aren’t any files left from the old install anymore but maybe there are some hidden files somewhere causing this .

Also I kept the add 'Anaconda to PATH " unchecked as per installation recommendations , Could that be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to keep all the software installations in C drive if you don't want to do extra path correction related work.

You have not updated the system environment path probably. There are residuals of anaconda pkg even after uninstallation. 
Remove the residual folder from there (`C:\anaconda3`). 
And update the environment path (Update the location from `C:\anaconda3\...` to `D:\anaconda3\...`).

Anaconda navigator issue should also get resolved after that.